# How to generate url for href in aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

How does one generate a `URL` in a master page's `ASPX` page so that the reference works everywhere across the app?

Here is an example from a menu in a master page:

```
<a href="Admin/AddVendor.aspx">Add Vendor</a>
```

The problem is that if I leave the `URL` as it is on the master page, then when someone is already on a page that resides in the Admin folder, this `URL` no longer works. 
I need to path the `URL` from the root every time, but forget how to do this in `WebForms`.

Comment: You need a root relative path, as opposed to document relative or absolute. Adobe has some [good information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html) on the differences.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using this, which maps to your website's root directory:

```
<a href="/Admin/AddVendor.aspx">Add Vendor</a>
```

**EDIT** : In that case, you could do this:

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Admin/AddVendor.aspx") %>">Add Vendor</a>
```

It would be far easier to just use the asp.net Hyperlink control though

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AddVendor.aspx" Text="Add Vendor" />
```

Comment: I tried this, but it knocks out the project name from the url and does not work.  Example: www.a.com/myproj/Admin/AddVendor.aspx actually results in www.a.com/Admin/AddVendor.aspx

Comment: @flying227 Updated the answer for your requirements.

Comment: @flying227 You're welcome. I'm curious though: did the `<a>` attribute with `Page.ResolveUrl` not work? Or did you not try it?

Comment: Yes, the <a> attribute with Page.ResolveUrl did work too.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

runat server html control could map site directory

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Admin/AddVendor.aspx">Add Vendor</a>
```